# Get the currently installed Shopware version in an App Script

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

Does anyone know, how to retrieve the currently installed Shopware 6 version in an App Script?

Unfortunately I was not able to find anything in the docs or the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We added support to retrieve the current shopware version from app scripts.
Refer to this [commit](https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/a1d5da6c5b7a32876bbd313a58289c9da635aeac).

Starting with 6.5.1.0 you can access the `shopware.version` variable from inside app scripts and also use it in combination with `version_compare`.

Answer (score 1):

When you're in the `dev` environment you can dump all available data within a script.

```
{% do debug.dump(hook) %}
```

When the script is executed you will find the dumped data under "Scripts" on the Symfony profile page of the corresponding request.

That being said I couldn't find anything relating to the current Shopware version in the available data of script hooks or by using the provided facade services. I'm fairly certain that, as of today, it's not possible to confirm the Shopware version using app scripts alone. If you're relying on that information please open an [issue ticket](https://issues.shopware.com/), as it is a feature request that can likely be implemented in a reasonable time.

Comment: Thanks @dneustadt!
Ticket is opened: https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-26010